# Pests on my herbs

Tags: pests, pest-control

I have some pests all over my herbs. They were on my chilli plant too a few weeks back, and I tried spraying it with a dilute mixture of apple cider vinegar with a couple of drops of washing up liquid in. I sprayed it a few times and the bugs kept coming back, so in the end I just let the chilli plant go. I'm not happy to give up on all of my herbs though.

I'm surprised that all want to hang out on my window frame. At least they're easy to get rid of from there!

Does anyone have some advice for getting  these pests off of my plants?

[image: pests1]
[image: pests2]